# How can I check command running result?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Inside a customised python interpreter, if run single command, I can see the command output.
But if I put commands into a file and run with execfile('file.py'), except print command, I can't see anything. It's hard to debug.
How can I check command output when run with execfile command?

Tried below commands to confirm the python version.

```
import sys
print sys.version_info[0],sys.version_info[1]
2 7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'command output' is not really a valid term. The Python interactive interpreter will echo the result of any [*expression statement*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-expression_stmt), unless that expression produced `None`. An expression statement is a top-level statement in a module body that only contains a single expression (as opposed to [other simple statements such as assignment or `import`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html) or [compound statements such as `if` or `while`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html). From the linked documentation:

> In interactive mode, if the value is not `None`, it is converted to a string using the built-in `repr()` function and the resulting string is written to standard output [...] on a line by itself. (Expression statements yielding `None` are not written, so that procedure calls do not cause any output.)

Doing so in a *script* would not be practical; you'd never be able to run any expression statement without the user of the script having to then decipher every little thing printed to the screen. Scripts usually want to control what is printed (to the point of not printing anything at all, but using logging instead, for example).

If you are using `execfile()` to run scripts, you could switch to parsing the script into an [abstract syntax tree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html), at which point you can transform the expression statement nodes to add printing. The resulting transformed AST can be fed directly to the `compile()` function, and the `exec()` function can take the output of the compilation step.

I'd use an extra global function passed to `exec()` here:

```
import ast

class ExprStatementPrinter(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_Expr(self, node):  # expression statement node
        # call the function __print_expr_result__, passing in the expression
        # contents; replace the original expression contents with that call.
        new_value = ast.Call(
            ast.Name('__print_expr_result__', ast.Load()),  # load as a global
            [node.value], [], None, None)  # node.value is the only argument
        # to be able to execute, we need to set the lineno and coll_offset; just
        # reuse the values of the expr node, then fix up any children
        node.value = ast.copy_location(new_value, node.value)
        return ast.fix_missing_locations(node)

def print_expr_result(result):
    if result is not None:
        print repr(result)

def execfile(filename):
    with open(filename) as source:
        tree = ast.parse(source.read())
    ExprStatementPrinter().visit(tree)  # updates the tree in-place
    codeobj = compile(tree, filename, 'exec')
    exec(codeobj, {'__print_expr_result__': print_expr_result})
```

I used a [double-underscore 'system' defined name](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers) for the print function to avoid collisions with anything the script might have defined.

Demo:

```
>>> example = '''\
... import sys
... sys.version_info[0],sys.version_info[1]
... 'Hello world!'
... None  # should not be printed
... '''
>>> exec(example)  # no output
>>> tree = ast.parse(example)
>>> ExprStatementPrinter().visit(tree)
<_ast.Module object at 0x1024c14d0>
>>> codeobj = compile(tree, '', 'exec')
>>> exec(codeobj, {'__print_expr_result__': print_expr_result})
(2, 7)
'Hello world!'
```

Note: this only applies to the *top-level file* you execute. Any imported modules are still going to be run without transformation (just like they would in the Python interactive interpreter). You'd have to hook into the `__import__` global to intercept the normal importing machinery.

Comment: Tried your demo, it's running fine. But if I try my script, it reports error. >>> example='reset.py' >>> tree = ast.parse(example) >>> ExprStatementPrinter().visit(tree)
<_ast.Module object at 0x7fba04333fd0> >>> codeobj = compile(tree, '', 'exec') >>> exec(codeobj, {'__print_expr_result__': print_expr_result}) NameError: name 'reset' is not defined. Did you mean one of reset, tree, test, regs, setsw, setpc, sethw, setdw, erase?

Comment: @Fisher: ah, in my demo session I used a string literal to define the script. Use the `execfile()` function in the code example I gave: `execfile('reset.py')`.

Comment: @Fisher: or use `example = open('reset.py').read()` first if you want to test with the exact same code I posted in the demo.

Comment: Tried: example = open('reset.py').read(), now it reports: >>> exec(codeobj, {'__print_expr_result__': print_expr_result})
Reset probe...
NameError: name 'probe' is not defined. Did you mean one of probe, probemode, protect, closeprobe, rbreg? So reset.py is running, but something is still wrong.

Comment: @Fisher: presumably you managed to solve that last issue? That's definitely not a problem introduced by my answer, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I'll debug this later. And strange, I can't @ your username.

Comment: That’s because you are commenting on my post and we are the only two people talking here. I get notified of all comments already, so there is no need to use `@myname`.

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks a lot!

Comment: For my case, seems add `print` in front of each command can do the trick.

Comment: @Fisher: that's what this code basically does, is *automatically* add a `print` for each command, and print the `repr()` representation (just like the console does). If you can easily just selectively add `print` statements to your code, however, then don't bother with this approach.