# Folium map doesn't open as .py file

Tags: python, folium

I created a map with Folium in Python. But when I save the code as .py and run it on the prompt, nothing happens.
The code works fine in Jupyter notebook, the map shows up in the output. But as a .py file, nothing shows up on the screen.
How do I fix that? (code below)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import folium
import geocoder
from folium.plugins import MeasureControl

g = geocoder.ip('me')
folium_map = folium.Map(location=[g.latlng[0],g.latlng[1]], zoom_start=13)
folium.Marker(location=[g.latlng[0],g.latlng[1]]).add_to(folium_map)

folium_map

folium_map.add_child(MeasureControl())
```

Comment: Try replacing that `folium_map` with `print(folium_map)`.  Echoing the values of expression statements is a common feature of interactive interpreters, but the regular Python interpreter doesn't do it.

Comment: See the first part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49895599/6779307)

Comment: Now I'm getting an output, but still no map shown  
The output given is:
<folium.folium.Map object at 0x000000CD0E6C8518>  

with a different number every time I run it. Any idea?

Comment: It looks like folium works by generating html that Jupyter notebook is smart enough to load in an iframe.  Basic Python doesn't have that functionality.  If you want to open your map, you'll have to send that data to a browser of some sort.  The folium documentation seems to assume you'll be using a Jupyter notebook.

Comment: See this issue: [show folium outside of ipython notebooks](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/946)

Comment: I have made a code in which the map is saved as a html file and I can open it in a browser with no issues. My problem, then, becomes a different one. My final product needs this map to be shown in a GUI made with tkinter. But as far as I could search, it's not possible to open a html with tkinter. If you have any idea for that problem, it'd be great

Comment: Either way, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you always save the map you create onto an html using:

```
folium_map = folium.Map()
folium_map.save('file_name.html')
```